# Python - Printing Integer variable inside double quote

Tags: python

I have an integer variable in Python::

> var = 10

I want to print it like this :

> "10"

Tried many things like

> ' "var" '

but did not really work.

Any help would really be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to convert integer to string ?

Comment: Converting is easy, i dont really want to convert it, i want to display it with double quote like "10"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use string [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format):

```
print('"{}"'.format(var))
# "10"
```

Or:

```
print("\"{}\"".format(var))
# "10"
```

Or:

```
print(f'"{var}"')
# "10"
```

Or:

```
print(f"\"{var}\"")
# "10"
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your variable yo string. like below:

```
print(str(var))
```

**EDIT**: Print in "10" style:

```
print('"{}"'.format(var))
```

Comment: It wouldn't be displaying output such as "10"
It will only give 10 as a string value

Comment: You need to convert or just print "" symbols?

Comment: yes thank you so much @Saeed it worked, can you please not down vote it?